# Set multiple page objects on request

Tags: java, html, spring, pagination, thymeleaf

Im on a Spring application and I have a view that is rendering 3 different and paginated tables using Thymeleaf like this

```
<tr th:each="order : ${ordersTypeX}">
```

So on my controller I add these Page to the model like this

```
 @GetMapping()
public String list(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("filter") OrderFilterDto filter, @SortDefault(value = ATTRIBUTE, direction = Sort.Direction.DESC) Pageable pageable) {
    log.info("Performing search");

    Page<OrderDto> ordersType1 = orderService.findByStatusId(1, pageable);
    Page<OrderDto> ordersType2 = orderService.findByStatusId(2, pageable);
    Page<OrderDto> ordersType3 = orderService.findByStatusId(3, pageable);

   
    model.addAttribute("ordersType1", ordersType1);
    model.addAttribute("ordersType2", ordersType2);
    model.addAttribute("ordersType3", ordersType3);

    return VIEW;
}
```

If i do this just for one attribute it's fine, problem comes when I add the other 2 that i need for the other tables, and it throws this exception:

```
    2023-04-28 11:10:06,359 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/app] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "templates/web/modules/pages/orders/lists.html")] with root cause
org.thymeleaf.dialect.springdata.exception.InvalidObjectParameterException: More than one Page object found on request!
```

Im not finding too much data about this problem, so thinks I would like to know is if im gonna be able at all to render these 3 tables on a single route mapping and view, or if i need to split into fragments or something (cant parametrize it much since data showed in each table is kind of different)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the full code of your controller.

Comment: Each of the 3 tables has its own pagination control elements like buttons, right? Then you must have a separate controller endpoint for each table with a pageable parameter.

Comment: but if its the same view, and each table is on a different tab, how can i manage to have 3 endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the solution was to call 3 different fragments with pagination in each one of them.